# problems with splitiing the range partition in oracle 12c

Tags: sql, plsql, split, oracle12c

I have a problem with splitting rang partition in oracle 12c.

i check it with some sources but I thought and saw it a lot. so may it has a simple error but I can't find it. please check this code. thanks.

---

first of all, I create this table

```
CREATE TABLE SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION
(
DEP_NO      NUMBER (20),
PART_NO     VARCHAR2 (30),
COUNTRY     VARCHAR2(20),
DATES       DATE,
AMOUNT      NUMBER (20)
)
PARTITION BY RANGE(DATES)
(
  PARTITION q1_2012  VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('2012/01/01','YYYY/MM/DD')),
  PARTITION q2_2012  VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('2012/04/01','YYYY/MM/DD')),
  PARTITION q3_2012  VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('2012/07/01','YYYY/MM/DD')),
  PARTITION q4_2012  VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('2013/10/01','YYYY/MM/DD'))
);
```

after that, I insert these data into it

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO PP_SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES (10, '4519b', 'FRANCE', (TO_DATE('2012/04/17','YYYY/MM/DD')), 45000)
  INTO PP_SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (20, '3788a', 'INDIA', (TO_DATE('2012/05/11','YYYY/MM/DD')), 75000)
  INTO PP_SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (40, '9519b', 'US', (TO_DATE('2012/09/18','YYYY,MM/DD')), 145000)
  INTO PP_SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (20, '3788a', 'PAKISTAN', (TO_DATE('2012/06/21','YYYY/MM/DD')), 37500)
  INTO PP_SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (40, '4577b', 'US', (TO_DATE('2012/06/30','YYYY/MM/DD')), 25000)
  INTO PP_SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (30, '7588b', 'CANADA', (TO_DATE('2012/03/26','YYYY/MM/DD')), 50000)
  INTO PP_SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (30, '9519b', 'CANADA', (TO_DATE('2012/09/09','YYYY/MM/DD')), 75000)
  INTO PP_SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (30, '4519b', 'CANADA', (TO_DATE('2012/06/08','YYYY/MM/DD')), 120000)
  INTO PP_SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (40, '3788a', 'US', (TO_DATE('2012/02/18','YYYY/MM/DD')), 4950)
  INTO PP_SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (10, '9519b', 'ITALY', (TO_DATE('2012/02/19','YYYY/MM/DD')), 15000)
  INTO PP_SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (10, '9519a', 'FRANCE', (TO_DATE('2012/02/06','YYYY/MM/DD')), 650000)
  INTO PP_SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (10, '9519b', 'FRANCE', (TO_DATE('2012/12/16','YYYY/MM/DD')), 650000)
  INTO PP_SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (20, '3788b', 'INDIA', (TO_DATE('2012/02/14','YYYY/MM/DD')), 5090)
  INTO PP_SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (40, '4788a', 'US',(TO_DATE('2012/09/17','YYYY/MM/DD')), 4950)
  INTO PP_SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (40, '4788b', 'US', (TO_DATE('2012/12/11','YYYY/MM/DD')), 15000)
  INTO PP_SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (20, '4519a', 'INDIA', (TO_DATE('2012/11/21','YYYY/MM/DD')), 650000)
  INTO PP_SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (20, '4519b', 'INDIA', (TO_DATE('2012/12/16','YYYY/MM/DD')), 5090)
  SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

and after that I try to split the last partition in two parts

```
 ALTER TABLE PP_SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION SPLIT PARTITION q4_2012 AT (TO_DATE('2012/11/15','YYYY/MM/DD') INTO 
  (
  PARTITION Q4_2012_P1,
  PARTITION Q4_2012_P2
  );
```

unfortunately it doesn't work. :(

please do me a favor and check this code. 
thanks.

Comment: Yes.. Check your code.. The table you created is not the same table you are inserting. The rror in the split partition is you did not close the parenthesis (TO_DATE('2012/11/15','YYYY/MM/DD') ).

Comment: `it doesn't work` is one of the most useless phrases in existence.  Do you get error messages?  If so, give them to us.  Does it run, but give undesirable results?  If so, tell us exactly what happens and what exactly you wanted to happen.

Comment: [It's Not Working](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) tends to get you voted down. The test case is handy though so I won't :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION
(
DEP_NO      NUMBER (20),
PART_NO     VARCHAR2 (30),
COUNTRY     VARCHAR2(20),
DATES       DATE,
AMOUNT      NUMBER (20)
)
PARTITION BY RANGE(DATES)
(
  PARTITION q1_2012  VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('2012/01/01','YYYY/MM/DD')),
  PARTITION q2_2012  VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('2012/04/01','YYYY/MM/DD')),
  PARTITION q3_2012  VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('2012/07/01','YYYY/MM/DD')),
  PARTITION q4_2012  VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('2013/10/01','YYYY/MM/DD'))
)
Table created.
SQL> INSERT ALL
  INTO SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES (10, '4519b', 'FRANCE', (TO_DATE('2012/04/17','YYYY/MM/DD')), 45000)
  INTO SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (20, '3788a', 'INDIA', (TO_DATE('2012/05/11','YYYY/MM/DD')), 75000)
  INTO SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (40, '9519b', 'US', (TO_DATE('2012/09/18','YYYY,MM/DD')), 145000)
  INTO SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (20, '3788a', 'PAKISTAN', (TO_DATE('2012/06/21','YYYY/MM/DD')), 37500)
  INTO SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (40, '4577b', 'US', (TO_DATE('2012/06/30','YYYY/MM/DD')), 25000)
  INTO SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (30, '7588b', 'CANADA', (TO_DATE('2012/03/26','YYYY/MM/DD')), 50000)
  INTO SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (30, '9519b', 'CANADA', (TO_DATE('2012/09/09','YYYY/MM/DD')), 75000)
  INTO SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (30, '4519b', 'CANADA', (TO_DATE('2012/06/08','YYYY/MM/DD')), 120000)
  INTO SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (40, '3788a', 'US', (TO_DATE('2012/02/18','YYYY/MM/DD')), 4950)
  INTO SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (10, '9519b', 'ITALY', (TO_DATE('2012/02/19','YYYY/MM/DD')), 15000)
  INTO SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (10, '9519a', 'FRANCE', (TO_DATE('2012/02/06','YYYY/MM/DD')), 650000)
  INTO SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (10, '9519b', 'FRANCE', (TO_DATE('2012/12/16','YYYY/MM/DD')), 650000)
  INTO SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (20, '3788b', 'INDIA', (TO_DATE('2012/02/14','YYYY/MM/DD')), 5090)
  INTO SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (40, '4788a', 'US',(TO_DATE('2012/09/17','YYYY/MM/DD')), 4950)
  INTO SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (40, '4788b', 'US', (TO_DATE('2012/12/11','YYYY/MM/DD')), 15000)
  INTO SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (20, '4519a', 'INDIA', (TO_DATE('2012/11/21','YYYY/MM/DD')), 650000)
  INTO SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION  VALUES  (20, '4519b', 'INDIA', (TO_DATE('2012/12/16','YYYY/MM/DD')), 5090)
  SELECT * FROM DUAL
17 rows created.
SQL> REM ## Gather stats and show row nums before the partiton split
SQL> BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS (
     OwnName           => 'SOA_USER1'
    ,TabName           => 'SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION'
    ,Estimate_Percent  => NULL
    ,Cascade           => TRUE
  ); 
END;
 PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
SQL> col partition_name for a20
SQL> select partition_name, NUM_ROWS from user_tab_partitions

PARTITION_NAME         NUM_ROWS
-------------------- ----------
Q1_2012                       0
Q2_2012                       5
Q3_2012                       5
Q4_2012                       7

4 rows selected.
SQL> ALTER TABLE SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION SPLIT PARTITION q4_2012 AT (TO_DATE('2012/11/15','YYYY/MM/DD')) INTO 
  (
  PARTITION Q4_2012_P1,
  PARTITION Q4_2012_P2
  )
Table altered.
SQL> REM ## Gather stats and show row nums before the partiton split
SQL> BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS (
     OwnName           => 'SOA_USER1'
    ,TabName           => 'SALES_SAMPLE_WITH_RANGE_PARTITION'
    ,Estimate_Percent  => NULL
    ,Cascade           => TRUE
  ); 
END;
 PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select partition_name, NUM_ROWS from user_tab_partitions

PARTITION_NAME         NUM_ROWS
-------------------- ----------
Q1_2012                       0
Q2_2012                       5
Q3_2012                       5
Q4_2012_P1                    3
Q4_2012_P2                    4

5 rows selected.
```